# get_description() function is returning null for order variation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i am using this below code to find the description of order variations, but the function is returning null

```
$order = wc_get_order(84687);

    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item ):

    $item_id = $item->get_id();

    ## Using WC_Order_Item_Product methods ##

    $product      = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product object
    $description = $product->get_description();

endforeach;
```

Comment: Are you sure `get_description()` actually returns a value or are you missing a return statement?

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm
function write_log ( $log )  {
      if ( is_array( $log ) || is_object( $log ) ) {
         error_log( print_r( $log, true ) );
      } else {
         error_log( $log );
      }
   }

i am using this function in functions.php and for printing out values i use write_log($description) but it is returning me null